# Проверка есть ли запрос

Tags: jquery, ajax

Доброго времени суток! можно ли проверить выполняется в данный момент какой-нибудь ajax запрос или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В jQuery есть два события [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) и [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/), а также свойство [jQuery.active](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L542) отвечающее за количество активных запросов.

P.S. Если при выполнении запроса выставить [global](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): `false`, такой запрос не будет учтен.